# TYPO3 V9.5.2 and V9.5.3 installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I wanted to know if any of you have encountered problems during installation by CPanel and Softacolous.

I also tried to proceed with a **manual installation**

My Hosting provider told me:
*Evidently this CMS in the latest version is not compatible with the cPanel system or requires an ad-hoc environment.
The manual procedure returns the same problems, we advise you to contact Typo3 support directly to debug the problem in more detail ...*

:(

Thanks

Comment: The obvious question: What is the error message you encounter?

Comment: Hi M,I should have completed the question.. My Hosting Provider contacted "CPanel" tech support and "Softacolous" tech support, so both confirmed that the problem was related to a script (I can't copy and paste it here because it is too long ... if you want I can send it by email) and then ... ...Evidently this CMS in the latest version is not compatible with the cPanel system or requires an ad-hoc environment. The manual procedure returns the same problems, we advise you to contact Typo3 support directly to debug the problem in more detail..

Comment: Please open a bug report at https://forge.typo3.org where you can paste the whole information

Comment: Ok, many thanks :)